# VB.NET different format date insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to insert data into SQL Server, but I have different format in datagridview data from is "dd/mm/yyyy" and after I see in my SQL Server format is "yyyy/mm/dd" that why I can't use where for update data.

In my SQL Server, the datatype is `Date`, and in my insert query

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells("Date").Value))
```

[vb format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz9ms.png) , [sql format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjIXK.png)

Comment: Formats are merely how software displays a date to a human.  If the DGV columns is Date and the DB field is Date, you simply update the DB using a `DateTime` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Format is irrelevant.  Format is only an issue when converting a `DateTime` to a `String` for display or when converting text input to a `DateTime`.  You should be storing binary dates in your database and binary dates are just numbers and have no format.  You should also be storing binary `DateTime` values in your grid.  How the grid displays them is irrelevant to how they're stored.

Here's what you should be doing.  Create a `DataTable` with a column for `DateTime` values, not `String` values.  You might do that manually or let a data adapter do it for you when you call `Fill`.  Bind that `DataTable` to your grid and configure the grid column to display the dates however is appropriate for the application.  Save any and all changes made to the grid by calling `Update` on the same data adapter.  You can use a command builder to generate the action commands or you can create them yourself.  Either way, you don't populate the parameters yourself but the data adapter draws the values from the `DataTable`.  If you're creating the commands manually, creating a parameter would look something like this:

```
myDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date, 0, "Date")
```

That tells the data adapter to get the values for the "@Date" parameter from the "Date" column of the `DataTable`.